# Refresh HTML page every new minute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of code, which refreshes my HTML page, everytime there is a new minute i.e. when seconds == 0.

```
<head>
<script>
    function reload(){
        location.reload();
    }
    function refresh(){
        var d = new Date();
        var s = d.getSeconds();
        if (s == 0) {setTimeout(reload(), 1000)};
    }
 </script> </head>
 <body onload="refresh(), setInterval('refresh()',1000)">
```

However, when it refreshes, it refreshes an infinite amount of times in the time that seconds == 0. I have tried to implement "setTimeout", in order to prevent this from happening - and so that it only refreshes once. However, this did not work and it is still refreshing an infinite amount of times while s == 0. Does anyone have any more ideas to prevent this from happening? Any questions, just ask. Thanks

Comment: Show us how you call refresh(), that might give a clue,

Comment: How refresh function is called? I think there is the gimic.

Comment: you an use setInterval(function() {
                  window.location.reload();
                }, 60000);

Comment: @user3751824 Read my comment to the answer below

Comment: remove `refresh()` before `setInterval` in `onload`. This is causing infinite loop. `<body onload="setInterval(refresh(),1000)">`

Comment: hahahah oh yeah, cant believe i didnt notice that :') thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to refresh after 1 minute from loading but refresh when second = 0.

You don't have to call refresh function constantly via interval.

We have current second. So, if we subtract from minute, we can find remaining seconds to new minute.

```
60 - d.getSeconds();
```

Then convert into milliseconds, set timeout, and page will be refresh exactly at new minute.

```
setTimeout(function() { location.reload() }, 1000 * (60 - d.getSeconds()));
```

If so important you can consider add/subtract milliseconds with `d.getMilliseconds()`

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, you can simplify this down to:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.location.reload(1);
}, 60 * 1000);
```

However a very simple solution not using JS is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; URL=https://example.com/">
```

Comment: You have misunderstood my intentions, I know how to refresh a page at a set interval. I need my page to be refreshed "every new minute".

Comment: @LukeRobinson ah i misunderstood. try changing `setTimeout(reload(), 1000)` to `setTimeout(reload, 1000)`

Comment: It’s okay, my query has been solved. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In general the refreshin is not a nice way to do things. have you considered using asychronous calls and refreshing your DOM with JavaScript instead of reloading the whole page?

However if you want to pursue this route I'd take the current starting time as a base and check from here is 1 second has passed already.

```
const t0 = performance.now();
function refresh(){
    if ((performance.now() - t0) >= 1000) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

However you'll need to call refresh untill this happens.

As for the "don't understand" comment, I cleand up a litle and I'll add some explanation here:

The first line is outside of all functions, so it sets a variable "globally", as it never changes I use a cosntant (instead of a variable) for speed and readability. It sets the current time in ms insode t0

```
const t0 = performance.now();
```

In your funcion I use the same command to get the ms again, and substract the formerly saved ms from it. If the new number is more than 1000 bigger than the original, a second has passed and it can do the reload.

```
if ((performance.now() - t0) >= 1000) {...
```

Comment: The whole page needs to be refreshed, much of the content within the page is ever changing from different files. Thanks for the answer, however i do not understand what you have done in the code I'm not going to lie...

Comment: I added some explanation. I hope that helps. ;-)